# How can you resize input & button elements to fit inside a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to resize my input elements and button elements to fit inside their parent div, because they go out of the div and break on mobile, i've been trying adjusting height with % but it didn't help as I suspected. I would like all buttons/inputs to fit inside their parent div at all times.

html and css

```css
body {
    background-color: dimgray;
}
.container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.builder {
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 90%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #272727;
    width: 45%;
}
.builder input {
    font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    color:#575757;
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.builder button {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: white;
    float: right;
    font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#575757;
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#color {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 10%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
::placeholder {
    color:#575757;
}
input:focus, input:hover, button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
button:hover {
    outline: none;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
.code {
    float: right;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 90%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #272727;
    width: 45%;
}
.code button {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.code textarea {
    margin-top: 5%;
    resize: none;
    color:#575757;
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 92.5%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.copy {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}

input:focus, input:hover, textarea:focus, textarea:hover {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Embed builder for Niko bot on Discord!">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#f186fc">
    <link href="./styling/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="assets/favicon.png">
    <title>Embed Builder</title>
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <div class="builder" id="builder">

            <input type="color" id="color">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Plaintext" id="plaintext" class="plaintext">

            <input type="url" placeholder="Icon URL" id="icon-url">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Thumbnail URL" id="thumbnail-url">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Title" id="title">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Description" id="description">

            <input type="url" placeholder="Image URL" id="image-url">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Footer Icon URL" id="footer-icon-url">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Footer Text" id="footer-text">

            <button onclick="submit()" id="submit">Get Code</button>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="code" id="code">
        <button onclick="copy()" class="copy" id="copy">Copy</button>
        <textarea id="code-box" readonly></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and inputs never go out from their parent.
Only buttons go out but at really tiny sizes, and that's due to buttons' font size: you have to make it responsive.

So for your buttons, you can set it like this: `font-size: min(5vw, 25px);`.
When the screen becomes very small, it will calibrate itself to the screen's width; when the screen gets bigger, it will stop growing at 25px.

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe I said the wrong thing, but when I resize the page width & height wise, the inputs go way off the parent div, what I meant by parent div is the div wrapping it, and what I mean by escaping the div is the inputs go outside of the padding.

Comment: Yea, also by running your snippet above and resizing the window, no inputs go outside `.container`.
Everything (inputs and buttons) stay inside the darker container... only buttons go a bit out if you make the window really really small. At least, that's what I see.

Comment: that's strange, on my website, and on localhost i'm running the same code and getting a completely different output. if you'd like to see what im seeing, the bugged site is, https://niko-bot.gitub.io

Answer (score 0):

in the parent of inputs and buttons put

```
    overflow:hidden
```

and also give to input and buttons

```
    max-width:100%
```

Comment: This made it so the overflowing elements just got completely cut off